# Box2D/AndEngine - ContactListener for multiple object classes

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I'm developing a little Android game in Java, using AndEngine for graphics and Box2D for physics - specifically, collision handling. I have some different types of objects with constructors in classes, like so:

```
MainActivity.java
Enemy.java
Npc.java
Door.java
```

I have a static PhysicsWorld in the main class, and I was setting up a ContactListener from the Enemy class, to define what happens when one of the enemies hits something. However, I tried to set up another ContactListener for the Door class, when I discovered that each PhysicsWorld has only one ContactListener.

Essentially, my question is this: what is the best way to get around this?

I'm aware I've probably explained this rather badly, so my apologies.

Comment: Just process all the different collisions you need to in that single `ContactListener` for your world.

Comment: But then how can I refer to the individual object that was in the collision? Say an enemy hits a wall, how do I tell that SPECIFIC enemy to change direction? I can't refer in a static way.

Comment: `Contact.getFixtureA/B()` will retrieve the two fixtures in contact. `Fixture.getBody()` will retrieve the `Body` object associated with the fixture, and, if you associate the `Enemy` or `Door` as a user data with a `Body`, use `Body.getUserData()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Is there any way to differentiate between A and B? And will this refer in a non-static way?

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-static way"?

Comment: Can I run methods inside the Enemy or Door, without making them static, from the CollisionListener?

Comment: If you have instances of the object, sure. I suggest you read the [relevant Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: I will do, thank you. If you'd like to add all this as an answer, I'll mark this solved? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your single `ContactListener` to manage the entire world; `Contact.getFixtureA/B()` will return the fixtures involved in the contact. You can utilize `Fixture.getBody()` to get the associated `Body` with each collision fixture; if, for example, your `Door` and `Enemy` objects are associated with the `Body`s as user data, then you can use `Body.getUserData()` to retrieve that.

Comment: How do I actually use a method in the object if I don't know what object is going to be in the collision? So say in my beginContact():

    contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData().someMethod();

Do I cast?

Comment: Use `instanceof` to test what kind of `Object` it is, e.g.
`if (bodyA.getUserData() instanceof Door) { ... }`

Comment: Can I then run a method from inside that specific instance?

Comment: So long as you cast to the appropriate type... :)